# Shopify Checkout Option like PayPal

Tags: shopify

We offer an additional checkout option for our merchant partners (similar to PayPal).

Customers can checkout by selecting our checkout button on the checkout page; these customers must have already registered with us and added a credit card to their account.

We offer two options for Merchants to integrate with us:

1. API (web services) or
2. Form (POST).

When a customer checks out by selecting our button, the following steps occur:

1. customer is presented with a login dialog to be authenticated
2. if successful and order is approved (by our back-end system), the customer is notified of this on the dialog box (web service) or form (hosted; then sent back to the merchants site).
3. the order in the merchants site is updated with the success status and with the customers billing/shipping information from our system.

Does Shopify have APIs that will allow us to do the steps above?

Comment: Hi there, could you please mark this question as answered if you’re confident in David’s answer?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct API to do this.

Shopify uses (a version of) [ActiveMerchant](http://activemerchant.org) for all payment processing services, both on-site (e.g. Stripe) and off-site (e.g. Paypal). If your service is integrated into ActiveMerchant, it can be integrated into Shopify.

HOWEVER:

Just being integrated into ActiveMerchant doesn't guarantee Shopify inclusion. We already integrate with many payment services, so any new offering must also be attractive on a business level as well as sound on a technical one before we'd consider adding it.